# How to down sample a dataframe in Python based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I am new here so don't know how to use this site.

I have a timeseries data of **37404 ICU Patients**. Each patient have multiple rows. I want to **down sample** my dataframe and **select** only **2932 patients** (all rows of the respective patient ID). Can anyone help me? My data looks like this:

| HR | SBP | DBP | Sepsis | P_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 92 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 0 |
| 98 | 115 | 85 | 0 | 0 |
| 93 | 125 | 75 | 0 | 1 |
| 95 | 130 | 90 | 0 | 1 |
| 102 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 1 |
| 109 | 115 | 75 | 0 | 2 |
| 94 | 135 | 100 | 0 | 2 |
| 97 | 100 | 70 | 0 | 3 |
| 85 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 4 |
| 88 | 115 | 75 | 0 | 4 |
| 93 | 125 | 85 | 0 | 4 |
| 78 | 130 | 90 | 0 | 5 |
| 115 | 140 | 110 | 0 | 5 |
| 102 | 120 | 80 | 0 | 5 |
| 98 | 140 | 110 | 0 | 5 |

I know I should use some condition on P_ID column, but I am confused.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) for random `P_ID` and filter in [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df2 = df[df['P_ID'].isin(np.random.choice(df['P_ID'].unique(), size=2932, replace=False))]
```

Alternative:

```
df2 = df[df['P_ID'].isin(df['P_ID'].drop_duplicates().sample(n=2932))]
```

EDIT: For random positions use:

```
df1 = df['P_ID'].drop_duplicates().sample(n=2932).to_frame('P_ID')

df2 = df.merge(df1, how='right')
```